# Is there a "most unstable rigid body shape" when spun about its intermediate axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, stability

Is there a shape of a solid, that provides the quickest and most violent deviation of its axis of rotation, when spun around its intermediate axis? What would be this shape and does it depend on a particular length ratio between the three axis, in this case is there a sweet spot ratio for getting the most unstable behaviour?

Comment: About the expression 'unstable behavour' that you use: the thing is: the effect is *cyclic*. The expression 'unstable', on the other hand, tends to be associated with chaotic behaviour. In chaotic behaviour there is never a cyclic repetion. Article by Nicholas Mecholsky (2018): [Analytic formula for the Geometric Phase of an Asymmetric Top](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03867) Mecholsky shows that the motion pattern is inherently periodic. So I recommend against using the word 'unstable'. Depending on the ratios of the moments of inertia the period of the cycle may be longer or shorter.

Comment: @Cleonis you're correct about the cyclic nature of the effect. now that you point it out, is it correct to say that once the effect is installed, the motion of the object can be predicted with great accuracy, yet short before it starts, there's a 50% chance the initial deviation starts one direction or an other, and is somehow unpredictable at this only point in time?

Comment: About the possibility to be on a knife edge: the mathematics of the idealized case does allow such a state. David Brown, author of the youtube channel 'Physics unsimplifed', has a video about [intermediate axis dynamics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJLdW4DHRcA&t=665s), in which he compares the overall cycle to the case of a rigid rod pendulum, started from inverted position. Example: release from an angle of 178 degrees: the rod will initially linger in that position, and once it starts going the rod will swing rapidly to the other side, slowing down to the position of -178 degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotation property of the solid only depends on its principal moment of inertia: $I_1\geq I_2\geq I_3$, so you can always revert to the case where it’s a brick, an ellipsoid or pretty much any shape you want. You’ll get the corresponding principle moments of inertia by squeezing it appropriately about the principle directions.

I would understand “the most unstable” by maximizing the Liapunov coefficient $\lambda$ which is the inverse timescale at which the rotational axis diverges from the intermediate axis. It is obtained by linearizing Euler’s equation about the unstable equilibrium. You get:
$$
\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{(I_1-I_2)(I_2-I_3)}{I_1I_3}}\Omega
$$
with $\Omega$ is angular velocity which is directed along the unstable intermediate axis. The fact that it is proportional to $\Omega$ is not surprising as by increasing the initial angular velocity necessary decreases the timescale from dimensional analysis (only timescale of the problem).

The answer to you question thus lies in the geometrical prefactor in front:
$$
C = \sqrt{\frac{(I_1-I_2)(I_2-I_3)}{I_1I_3}}
$$
which you must seek to maximize by squeezing appropriately your shape. Note that it can take any value you want, especially arbitrarily large ones. The problem would be more interesting if you were to add constraints like fixing volume, mass, minimum/maximum radius etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can show that $C$ is maximized at $I_2=\tfrac 1 2(I_1+I_3)$. In other words: we want to make the difference between $I_1$ and $I_3$ as large as possible (i.e. make $I_1$ as large as possible and $I_3$ as small as possible) and then put $I_2$ in the middle.

Comment: This helps a lot, constraints are real world materials and human scale, for instance shaping it from .1kg of aluminium alloy, sets minimum thicknesses, and/or maximal lengthes of the truss elements it will be composed of, so that when tested it still acts as a solid, and doesn't break when it hits the floor.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion this makes it very intuitive, appreciated